# all possible paths between two nodes in a matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, search

I have a matrix with four column1 Linknumbers(not important now), column2: start, column3:end and column4 if greater than 0 -> then the nodes are connected. I have written a recursive code but it doesnt show the output properly: for instance:
between node 1 and 18 it outputs

```
path=[1 2 6 8 16 18] % which is correct
path=[1 2 6 8 16 7 18] % from 8 there are two paths (16 and 7)- it shouldnt show 16 anymore

% the code is
function findpaths(Matrix,start, destination,pathD)
if(start==destination)
   pathD % have a problem in storing them too (it just outputs now)
   return
end
    % to find all the rows that have start 
    % then it can find all the nodes connected to start 
    % if start is 6 then it return 4 and 9th row where 
    %there are 8 and 5 connected to 6 in those rows
    [row] = find(Matrix(:,2)==start); % to find all the rows that have this node

        for i=1:size(row,1) % adjecent nodes to start
            if Matrix(row(i),4)>0 % condition to see if the nodes are connected
                adj_node = Matrix(row(i),3);  % the adjacent node              
                if ismember(adj_node, pathD)==0
                    pathD;
                    pathD = [pathD adj_node];
                    start = adj_node;
                    findpaths(Matrix,start,destination,pathD);
                end
            end
        end
   end
```

below is the matrix

```
1   1   2   1

2   1   3   0

4   2   6   1

16  6   8   1

6   3   4   0

7   3   12  0

21  8   9   0

10  4   11  0

15  6   5   0

22  8   16  0.5

20  8   7   0.5

37  12  13  0

32  11  10  0

25  9   10  0

49  16  17  0

18  7   18  0.5

28  10  15  0

50  16  18  0.5

34  11  14  0

53  17  19  0

39  13  24  0

46  15  22  0

56  18  20  0

42  14  23  0

76  24  23  0

62  20  21  0

69  22  21  0
```

Comment: Try http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10922-matlabbgl

Comment: I have already seen this toolbox; it's not very clear how to use it. I get the feeling that the code is a translation from C and its not easy to follow with function to use

Comment: Actually it's a very powerful toolbox, it's written in C (which is why it is so good) and there is a manual - I think you should definitely read it.

Comment: thanks Franck for your suggestion. But honestly, I spent couple of hours trying to figure out how to make the matrix and how to run the code. It is very ambiguous and though it looks very sophisticated code but I believe I need to spend days to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Ramin, I need to know: how many nodes and edges do you have? Can you re-write your matrix as an N-by-N adjacency matrix? Also, have you tried http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27438-find-all-the-possible-paths-between-a-start-and-an-end-node-of-a-graph ?

Answer (score 0):

Well most of the algorithms, at least the ones I found, implementing BFS or DFS will output the nodes they visit - for instance when a dead-end is visited, upon backtracking, the deadend node is also is truly shown in the path. The main issue is to create a queue data structure in matlab; I couldnt find any useful available Queue implementations, so I used structures (I am sure it's not a very efficient way but I need to store data in matlab in the following format, for instance:

```
[['1', '4', '8'], ['1', '2', '5', '9'], ['1', '2', '5', '10'], ['1', '4', '7', '11']]

the Pseudo code is:
function [nodes,links] = bfs4(GRAPH, start, destination)% def BFS(graph,start,end,q):

nodes=struct;
links=struct;
path = struct;

temp_path = start;


last_node=[];
% q.enqueue(temp_path)
path(1).data = temp_path;


    while size(fieldnames(path),1)~=0
        tmp_path = path(1).data;
        if length(path) == 1
            path=struct;
        else
            path = path(2:end);
        end
        last_node = tmp_path(end);

    %         Storing the nodes in Two Forms (NODEs) and (LINKs)
        if last_node == destination
             tmp_path;

             if size(fieldnames(nodes),1)==0
             nodes(end).data=tmp_path
             else
                nodes(end+1).data=tmp_path
             end
%             taking the links 
         link=[];
            for i=1:(length(tmp_path)-1)
                link(i) = GRAPH(GRAPH(:,2)==tmp_path(i) & GRAPH(:,3)==tmp_path(i+1));
            end
            if size(fieldnames(links),1)==0
                links(end).data=link;
            else
                links(end+1).data=link;
            end
        end

        [row] = find(GRAPH(:,2)==last_node);
        for i=1:size(row,1)
     %              be careful -- the condition to be remove GRAPH(row(i),10)>0
             if   GRAPH(row(i),10)>0 && ismember(GRAPH(row(i),3),tmp_path)==0  
                   new_path=[];
                   new_path = [tmp_path GRAPH(row(i),3)];
                   if size(fieldnames(path),1)==0
                       path(end).data = new_path;
                   else
                       path(end+1).data = new_path;
                   end

             end
        end

    end % while
end % function
```